# PHP: Using is_null() with !$var or isset($var)

Tags: php

While I believe the answer is *yes*, I have seen the following in legacy code so much, I'm doubting myself. I'm asking for a sanity check from the community.

#### Legacy Code

```
if (is_null($result) || !$result) {
```

#### Refactored Code

```
if (!$result) {
```

***Note:*** I am aware this will throw a Notice if `$result` is not set.

#### Question

Is this code logically equivalent?

#### Code Tests

I tested with all the combinations of [PHP false values](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) without receiving *Not equal for ...*.

```
$false_values = array(false, 0, 0.0, '0', '', null, array(), new stdClass());

foreach ($false_values as $var) {
    if (!$var != (is_null($var) || !$var)) {
        echo 'Not equal for: ';
        var_dump($var);
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
$ php check.php
$
```

Comment: You should also add the response of your script ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, both snippets are equivalent. [is_null](http://php.net/is_null) is defined as:

> Returns TRUE if var is null, FALSE otherwise.

The documentation also makes it clear that `is_null` throws out a warning when the variable is undefined, as does a simple boolean evaluation of `$result`. If `$result` is unset, `is_null($result)` is true and you therefore get one warning - the same behavior as you'd with `!$result`.

Since the boolean evaluation of NULL is (unsurprisingly) false, we can simply test out all interesting values:

```
$result  is_null($result)  !$result   is_null($result) || !$result
(unset)   true(+warn)     true(+warn)          true (+warn)
null         true            true              true
false(-y)    false           true              true
true(-ish)   false           false             false
```

Note that the results of `is_null` and `!$result` are identical for all values that evaluate to false as well for all ones evaluating to true. Therefore, no further distinction (say, by testing `0`, `""`, etc.) is necessary.

Answer (score 5):

A `null` variable will evaluate to `false` in a boolean context. So the statements are logically equivalent - when the variable is null it will be caught by the `!$result` statement.

Use [`empty()`](https://www.php.net/empty) to prevent a notice-level warning:

```
if (!empty($result)) {
   // do something
}
```

Comment: + for the note about empty not generating a warning.

Answer (score 1):

Due to http://php.net/is_null the call `is_null($var)` should be the very same as `$var === NULL`.

As testing `!$var` tests for a value so any null, empty, non-existent/not set or zero value is transformed into boolean **false** and any other into boolean **true**.

Therefore calling `(is_null($result) || !$result)` while `$result` will be any of Your `$false_values` will result in:

```
false          : (is_null(false) || !false)      => (false || true) => true
0              : (is_null(0) || !0)              => (false || true) => true
0.0            : (is_null(0.0) || !0.0)          => (false || true) => true
'0'            : (is_null('0') || !'0')          => (false || true) => true
null           : (is_null(null) || !null)        => (true || true)  => true
array()        : (is_null(array()) || !array())  => (false || true) => true
new stdClass() : (is_null(new cls) || ! new cls) => (false || true) => true
```

As test for `!$var` in Your test should always be `true` **it is very O.K. You didn't get `Not equal for`**.

If You want to avoid notices, You could use this test:

```
if(isset($var) && $var) echo 'true story';
```

or

```
if(!isset($var) || !$var) echo 'this happens if false or not set at all';
```

Answer (score 0):

code is logical equivalent as:

```
is_null(null) === true
and
!null === true
```

Yes and as leepowers said use `empty()`